# pandas the frequency of occurrence of unique values in all the table by category of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there is a column with 4 categories, I want to display the frequency of occurrence of values of other columns for each unique value
**example of partial Data**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example DataFrame and an example output?

Comment: @965311532 [link](https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-49/s/v1/if2/XVHdEn00oVzhXSDBK9eI4eZLVnO2G5ZKFTwFI-gUKFxqCZgXmHHTdPadpCz9sm1v-YJusiPrqWtaYsYbdS8BVMAj.jpg?size=990x209&quality=96&type=album) example data

Comment: @965311532 [link](https://sun5.userapi.com/sun5-4/s/v1/if2/efyJiz-9X0QQz2BcYDTbpKVf5VdtJQ9usyMantmz0iSj97xGCQVnjregNCFagWGnWRVSAaEzGgsPSmIIQFAB1G8U.jpg?size=540x81&quality=96&type=album) example output and I need to do this for all the other tables, and for quantitative ones, find the minimum maximum and average

Comment: @SergeiSemenets your links may be unreachable from some regions (I need to use VPN to see them). It would be nice to add this screenshots of a data example and a desired output to your question. Use _Image_ menu or press Ctrl+G when edit to add a picture. BTW Have you tried using `pivot`?

Comment: @SergeiSemenets I added a solution that should work for you. I had to be general, as you haven't provided too much detail to work with. In the future, try to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BENY , sorry bothering you, but I like the way you code. I'm curious, if you have 5min, would you have a variant to proposing us?

Comment: @Drakax who is @BENY?

Comment: @SergeiSemenets if the answer is what you were looking for, be sure to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cat1": ["yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"],
        "cat2": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"],
        "cat3": ["yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no"],
        "quant": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)
```

Sample DataFrame:

```
    cat1 cat2 cat3  quant
0   yes  a    yes   1
1   no   a    no    2
2   yes  b    no    3
3   no   b    yes   4
4   yes  a    no    5
```

You can do:

```
y = lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).loc["yes"]
n = lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).loc["no"]
df.groupby(["cat2"]).agg(
    {
        "cat1": [("yes", y), ("no", n)],
        "cat3": [("yes", y), ("no", n)],
        "quant": ["min", "max", "mean"],
    }
)
```

Result:

```
      cat1                  cat3                   quant
      yes           no      yes         no         min  max mean
cat2                            
a     0.666667  0.333333    0.333333    0.666667    1   5   2.666667
b     0.500000  0.500000    0.500000    0.500000    3   4   3.500000
```

Here's a slightly more robust version:

```
from functools import partial

def agg_func(s: pd.Series, name: str):
    try:
        return s.value_counts(normalize=True).loc[name]
    except KeyError:
        return 0


yes_no_agg = [
    ("yes", partial(agg_func, name="yes")),
    ("no", partial(agg_func, name="no")),
]

df.groupby(["cat2"]).agg(
    {
        "cat1": yes_no_agg,
        "cat3": yes_no_agg,
        "quant": ["min", "max", "mean"],
    }
)
```

Comment: There's a minor bug in case if no 'yes' or 'no' values found. Also you're counting values twice for each category. Isn't it possible to do it once and put the result along the row? If there's more then two answers `['yes','no']`, should we write a separate function for each new case?

Comment: You're right in pointing out that this isn't the most generalisable solution possible. I wrote it as a quick-and-dirty solution to the images that OP shared. Let me try to improve it

Comment: Nicely done with`yes_no_agg` 

Answer (score 1):

## How to generate descriptive information by category

I propose to separate two cases. One is numerical data to see their min, max and average by category. The other is labeled data and their frequency distribution.

### Min, max, mean of numerical data by category

First, let's prepare the data with `'mode'` as a category column and two numerical fields `'Measure1', 'Measure2'`:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'mode': ['i','i','i','ii','ii','iii','ii','iii','ii'],
        'Ofloxacin': ['no','no','no','yes','no','no','yes','no','no'],
        'ChangeMode': ['yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','yes'],
        'Measure1': [*range(1, 10)],
        'Measure2': [*range(-9, 0)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In this case, I propose to use `DataFrame.describe` to generate statistics for numerical data:

```py
df.groupby('mode').agg('describe')
```

In the output we can find `min, max, mean`:
[image: min max mean by category for numerical data]

### Labeled data and their frequency distribution by category

#### 1. The same labels in different columns

In this particular case we can see that columns `'Ofloxacin','ChangeMode'` are labeled the same. For that reason, let's use `DataFrame(...).stack` to form rows with label distribution data by categories and fields:

```py
columns = ['Ofloxacin','ChangeMode']
df.groupby('mode')[columns].apply(lambda group: (
    pd.DataFrame((group.value_counts(col, True) for col in columns), index=columns)
    .stack(dropna=False)
    .fillna(0)
    .sort_index()
    ) 
)
```

Here's the output on the same data as in the previous case:
[image: distribution of labels by category]

#### 2. Different labeling in different columns.

Let's add new columns with slightly more varied content:

```py
data = {'mode': ['i','i','i','ii','ii','iii','ii','iii','ii'],
        'Ofloxacin': ['no','no','no','yes','no','no','yes','no','no'],
        'ChangeMode': ['yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','yes'],
        'Reaction': ['good','bad','so-so','good','good','so-so','bad','bad','good'],
        'DummyData': 'hello my world and all the people out there'.split()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In this case, the previous solution won't work. To fix it, let's prepare a multi index for expected columns:

```py
from functools import reduce

columns = ['Ofloxacin','ChangeMode','Reaction','DummyData']
multicol = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    reduce(
        lambda x, y: x.append(y),
        (
            pd.Index(sorted(df[col].unique()))
            .map(lambda label: (col, label))
            for col in columns
        ),
        pd.Index([])
    )
)
```

I'm gonna use it to store data in the right place like this:

```py
final_output = df.groupby('mode')[columns].apply(
    lambda group:
        pd.DataFrame(
            (group.value_counts(col, True) for col in columns), 
            index=columns 
        ).stack().reindex(multicol)
).fillna(0)
```

Here's the final output:

[image]

---

p.s. The [notebook on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x9HokPTPGJWuIutSosAZTl1f7U-_b--R?usp=sharing) for experiments